# How to read XLSB file with ODBC

Tags: c#, odbc, xlsb

I have this code, which I would like to convert `.xlsb` file to `DataTable`

```
public static class Utils
    {
        public static DataTable ImportExceltoDatatable(string filepath)
        {

            string connectionString = "Driver ={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)}; DBQ = " + filepath;

            string query = "Select * From [SheetName$]";

            using (var connection = new OdbcConnection(connectionString))
            using (var adapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(query, connection))
            {
                DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
                adapter.Fill(dataset); // <---------------- exception thrown here

                DataTable datatable = dataset.Tables[0];
                return datatable;
            };
        }
    }
```

`adapter.Fill(datasaet)` throws the following exception

> System.Data.Odbc.OdbcException: 'ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver
> Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified'

In computer ODBC settings, Excel driver seems to be installed
[image]

what is the correct way of how to use this driver, do I have a mistake in the connection string?

Unfortunately, I found no other way than to use ODBC.

- **NPOI**, **EPPLUS** does not read XLSB.
- **LinqToExcel** needs `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` registered on the machine.
- **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** needs excel to be installed on the machine.

Comment: Have your application show the result of `String.Format("{0}-bit", IntPtr.Size * 8)`. What does it say?

Comment: it says 32-b, I will try to run program in 64-b mode

Comment: I switched to 64-b, but the error message is the same.

Comment: Make sure you have the right driver - http://help.loftware.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=27099554

Comment: Try using [AceOdbcCheck](https://github.com/gordthompson/AceOdbcCheck) to check your ODBC setup.

Comment: I don't get it, because in `odbc data source administrator window` the driver for `.xlsb` is already listed ?

Comment: Have you tried to use ACE.OLEDB driver? See: [Xlsb files using Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0](https://www.connectionstrings.com/ace-oledb-12-0/xlsb-files/)

Comment: @Muflix - The driver information may have been written to the Windows registry but the driver itself may be installed in such a way that it is only accessible to Microsoft Office and isn't directly available to third-party applications. That's why I suggested trying [AceOdbcCheck](https://github.com/gordthompson/AceOdbcCheck).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem just now. In your pic you can see the "Platform" column says the driver is 64-bit. Switching the project to x64 (instead of Any CPU) fixes the problem.